# Prove if $x > 100$ then $\frac{100}{3-2x} > -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

If $x > 100$ then $\frac{100}{3-2x} > -1$

Pf:

- Assume $x>100$

  - $-2x > -20$
  - $-2x + 3 > -200$
  - $\frac{1}{3-2x} > \frac{1}{-200}$

This is what I have done so far, however I'm not sure how to proceed from here on out. If anyone has any tips, or possibly and example to further push me in the right direction I'd appreciate it greatly!

Comment: Your proof is erroneous. Multiplying by $-2$ flips the inequality sign and then taking the reciprocal of two negative numbers on both sides of the inequality again flips the inequality sign.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful! From $2>1$ you cannot deduce that $-200>-100$.

From $x>100$ you can deduce that $2x>200$ and so that
$$
2x-3>200-3=197
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{1}{2x-3}<\frac{1}{197}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{100}{2x-3}<\frac{100}{197}<1
$$
Changing sign reverses inequalities, so
$$
-\frac{100}{2x-3}>-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x > 100 \Rightarrow 2x > 200 \Rightarrow -2x < -200 \Rightarrow 3 - 2x < -197 \Rightarrow 2x - 3 > 197 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2x-3} < \dfrac{1}{197} \Rightarrow \dfrac{100}{2x-3} < \dfrac{100}{197} \Rightarrow \dfrac{100}{3-2x} > -\dfrac{100}{197} > -1 $.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if $x>100$, $\;3-2x<0$, hence both sides of the inequality have the same sign. Change these signs and take the reciprocals to obtain an equivalent inequality  (both transformations reverse the inequality):
$$\frac{2x-3}{100}>1\iff 2x > 103$$
which is trivially satisfied if $x>100$.

Answer (score -4):

By plugging in $x = 100$ in the denominator, we have

$$ \frac{100}{3-2x} > -\frac{100}{197} > -1$$

Comment: That solves the inequality for one value of $x$. We need to prove it for all values of $x > 10$.

Comment: $3 - 2x < -197$ $\forall x > 100$ so it holds for every value of $x$.

Comment: You did not show how to prove that. You should delete this answer and make a new one explaining why that is.

Comment: "By plugging in..."

Comment: You can not plug in every value of $x > 100$. There is a way to prove $3-2x<-197$ for all $x > 100$ without plugging in.

Comment: I did not say plugging in every value of $x$.